# JUnit Error: Failed to load ApplicationContext: Offending resource: class path resource

Tags: java, spring, junit, applicationcontext

I have been trying to configure application context in Junit like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "../application.xml")
public class TestClass{
.....
}
```

The error I get when I run the JUnit is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee]
Offending resource: class path resource [application.xml]
```

Any idea what might have wrong?

Comment: You can't use a relative-file-path format. Use a proper classpath-based path (e.g., put your `application.xml` in `src/main/resources` and just say `locations = "application.xml"`).

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I guess its not the problem. It is able to find the application.xml file. But when it reads it, there is this issue.

Comment: Spring version pls

Comment: @DineshDontha Spring version is 4.1.5

Comment: Use @ContextConfiguration("/application.xml"). If did not work, please post your project structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your `application.xml` starts with this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">
    
...

</beans>
```

Comment: Thanks. Mistake was with my application.xml